# SoundCloud fetching artwork_url gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: android, soundcloud, picasso

I'm trying to display SoundCloud images in a RecyclerView using the artwork_url for a track and downloading/displaying them with Picasso. When the app first loads I get a 403 from SoundCloud for the images in the rows being displayed.

The images download when scrolling which makes me think that maybe there's some throttling/rate limiting happening and the initial loading of the screen asks for too many images in too short of a time.

I think the problem is with SoundCloud and not Android/Picasso since I've tried other URLs and had the images load with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 is S3's way of saying File Not Found. I don't know exactly why they don't use 404... Sometimes the transcoding of the image fails, and so the artwork at that size may be unavailable. The solution is to try another size, or use a fallback image in tgese cases.

Comment: Thanks! Should `-original` always work then? Btw, I'm looking at the most recently created tracks so it completely makes sense that the artwork might not be available yet.